# How to iterate through an array and assign each item to each dictionary key

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have an array and a dictionary

```
var list = ["A", "B", "C","D"]

var dict = [
    "Chapter 1 Body" : "",
    "Chapter 2 Body" : "",
    "Chapter 3 Body" : "",
    "Chapter 4 Body" : ""
]
```

I would like to iterate through the list array and assign each item to each key of the dictionary. Here is the expected output when I print dict:

```
["Chapter 1 Body": "A", "Chapter 2 Body": "B", "Chapter 3 Body": "C", "Chapter 4 Body": "D"]
```

**Note:** The order should be the same as the printed output.

Comment: Dictionaries do not have any order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var i = 0
for k in dict.keys.sorted() {
    dict[k] = list[i]
    i += 1
}
```

Comment: Hey, the problem is that this isn't sorted

Comment: @SMALLworld Sorry. Fixed.

Comment: Oh noice, just one more question, is it possible to print it in the order I've shown in my question?

Comment: @SMALLworld Dictionaries. Have. No. Order. You shouldn't care about the order in which their contents are printed. It is meaningless and irrelevant.

Comment: @SMALLworld you cannot if you use Dictionaries, but if you use JSON for example (from external libraries), then it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` and sort the keys (if alphabetical sort order is correct order for the dictionary keys)

```
dict = zip(dict.keys.sorted(), list).reduce(into: [:]) {$0[$1.0] = $1.1}
```

If the keys are sorted in some other order then you need to have them in an array instead in the correct order but the solution is basically the same

```
var chapters = ["Chapter 1 Body", "Chapter 2 Body", "Chapter 3 Body", "Chapter 4 Body"]
let dict = zip(chapters, list).reduce(into: [:]) {$0[$1.0] = $1.1}
```